# No firefox update ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, updates, firefox

I am amazed this never happened for so long but I noticed that firefox is no longer being upgraded on my ubuntu 14.04 so I am stuck on 38

Will canonical upgrade the firefox in 14.04 soon if not is there a stable official firefox ppa for ubuntu 14.04 that will get latest stable ff updates ??

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be updated, when maintainers decide.

Stable 39 has been released on July 2.

Next version can be installed from ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

This is an [Official Firefox PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next)

**Note:** Generally this ppa contains next beta version of Firefox. I do no recommend keeping this ppa always connected. It can be removed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

but packages installed from this ppa will stay. No new updates will be done.

**Update:** Firefox 39 is already available from standard Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Is it an official firefox ppa ??

Comment: @Levan Added to the answer.

Comment: By definition none PPA is "official" even if you put the word "official" on it's name.

Comment: @xangua This a matter of definition of "official". This PPA is maintained by Canonical.

Comment: Take care that this repository, although official, has Firefox Beta and not Firefox stable. So it is not meant for end users but more for testing purpose. There is another official repository which built Firefox current (it has already Firefox 39) but this is also for testing purpose. Once testing has been done in this later repository, the build will be made available via standard updates. https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Now it contains stable 39. I think this week it will be published in MORE official repositories. It is in wily-proposed already.

Answer (score 1):

1 more day of waiting is all what you had to do: the "official" FF 39.0 was deployed yesterday without the help of any PPA …

**Low quality reviewers:** That's it!  **;-)**

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have solution on 11.10, on Ubuntu 11.10 current firefox version is 20. Probably work all versions of Ubuntu.

Download latest version of firefox archive from mozilla https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/

extrack on tmp or some other directory. Just use extracted directory.

Open new terminal and kill firefox `killall firefox`

Get a root permission via `sudo su`

```
cd / 
mv /usr/lib/firefox /usr/lib/firefox.old
```

and then go to the directory of the /usr/lib/firefox.old and make a one copy of firefox.sh to your desktop

and copy new version of firefox from tmp to lib

```
cd /
mv /tmp/firefox /usr/lib/firefox
```

and then firefox.sh paste from desktop to usr/lib/firefox

firefox.sh for a launcher from sidebar firefox icon.

If you broke the firefox open terminal

```
killall firefox
sudo su
cd /
rmdir /usr/lib/firefox
mv /usr/lib/firefox.old /usr/lib/firefox
```

This solution works for other integrated unsupported distribution (LibreOffice etc.)